# "Ninguna instancia de función sobrecargada" y "noexcept const': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'const _Ty' a 'const _Elem'" usando find de C++

Tags: c++, poo

Si yo tengo dos clases, **Categoría** y **Actor**:

**Actor.h**

```
#define _ACTOR_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Actor {
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Actor& actor);

    private:
        string nombre, apellidos;
        bool trabajando;
        float sueldo;

    public:
        Actor(string nombre, string apellidos);
        string getNombre() const;
        string getApellidos() const;
        bool estaTrabajando() const;
        void setEstaTrabajando(bool trabajando);
        void anyadirSueldo(float sueldo);
};

#endif
```

¿Por qué no puedo hacer lo siguiente en **Categoria.cc**?

```
int Categoria::encontrarActores(string nombre) const {
            // Siendo actores: vector<Actor> actores;

            for (unsigned i = 0; i < actores.size(); i++) {
                if (nombre.find(actores[i]) != string::npos)
                    return i;
            }
        
            return -1;
 }
```

En el if me salen dos errores y no los entiendo, ¿es porque no puedo utilizar "find" con una clase y solo lo puedo utilizar con un vector normal?

*Ninguna instancia de función sobrecargada "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::find [con _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits, _Alloc=std::allocator]" coincide con la lista de argumentos*

*unsigned int std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>::find(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator> &,const unsigned int) noexcept const': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'const _Ty' a 'const _Elem' POO*

Comment: De qué tipo es la variable `actores`?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tipo de `actores`?

Comment: Actores viene de un vector de la clase Actor: vector<Actor> actores;

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la definición de `Actor`?

Comment: Actor tiene: string nombre, string apellidos, bool trabajando, float sueldo.

Comment: Y también tiene el constructor, void getNombre, void getApellidos, bool estaTrabajando, void setEstaTrabajando, void anyadirSueldo y friend

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade la declaración de `Actor` y de `actores`. Los comentarios no están pensados para añadir partes fundamentales de la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a ver el error:

> unsigned int std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>::find(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator> &,const unsigned int) noexcept const': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'const _Ty' a 'const _Elem' POO

Sabemos que la función [`string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) devuelve un `size_type` que es un entero sin signo y espera recibir un `std::string`, un `char` o un `char *`:

**Sobrecargas de `std::string::find`**:

- `constexpr size_type find( const basic_string& str, pos = 0 ) const noexcept;`.
- `constexpr size_type find( const CharT* s, size_type pos, size_type count ) const;`.
- `constexpr size_type find( const CharT* s, size_type pos = 0 ) const;`.
- `constexpr size_type find( CharT ch, size_type pos = 0 ) const noexcept;`.
- `template < class T > constexpr size_type find( const T& t, size_type pos = 0 ) const noexcept`.

Ninguna de las sobrecargas acepta un objeto de tipo `Actor`. Seguramente quieres pasarle alguno de los datos contenidos en actor.

Comment: "Ninguna de las sobrecargas acepta un objeto de tipo `Actor`". Menuda sorpresa si así fuera, jaja.

Comment: @Andrew cualquiera de las sobrecargas aceptaría un objeto de tipo `Actor` si dicho objeto tuviese un operador de conversión a `std:.string`, `char` o `char *`; pero ya sabemos que no es el caso.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Exacto, quiero pasarle "nombre", que está dentro de "Actor". Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.